# replaceAll doesn't affect the string

Tags: java, regex

I trying to use regex within the `replaceAll` function. I need to do a real simple task which is to switch ever = and ~ operator with a : char with no spaces!

For instance:

```
(srcIP = 0.0.0.0) AND (dstIP~0.0.0.0 OR protocol  =     TCP)
```

turns to

```
(srcIP:0.0.0.0) AND (dstIP:0.0.0.0 OR protocol:TCP)
```

I am trying to use the following code

```
query.replaceAll("[ ]*(=|~)[ ]*", ":");
```

but it doesn't work. Is there any way to do this using `replaceAll` function? It seems that it doesn't work with regex.

Comment: `replaceAll` and `replace` don't change the `String`, they create a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
System.out.println("(srcIP = 0.0.0.0) AND (dstIP~0.0.0.0 OR protocol = TCP)".replaceAll("[ ]*(=|~)[ ]*", ":"));
```

works fine for me

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is fine (although it can be improved). Proof:

```
System.out.println("(srcIP = 0.0.0.0) AND (dstIP~0.0.0.0 OR protocol = TCP)".replaceAll("[ ]*(=|~)[ ]*", ":"));
```

Prints:

```
(srcIP:0.0.0.0) AND (dstIP:0.0.0.0 OR protocol:TCP)
```

Strings are immutable in Java, [`replaceAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) doesn't modify the string in-place, it returns a new one. You're probably not assigning the result back.

Your regex can be rewritten as:

```
\\s*[=~]\\s*
```

Comment: You are absolutely right I forgot it is immutable thanks.